# Mail notification issue

Tags: python, pyspark

In our project, we are running pyspark script (.py) through unix wrapper script (.sh)
    In the scenario where script fails, mail notification is sent from sh script to all users.
    I was trying to raise one simple ValueError as below:

```
if ([i for i in list1 if i is not None]):
    l = [i.encode('utf-8') for i in list1 if i is not None]
    raise ValueError("Failed..." + str(l)) 
else:
    pass
```

It will raise error if list contains not none parameter. But issue is in the mail notification i am getting error like:

> Status: Failed Message: raise ValueError("Scripts failed..." + str(l)) ValueError: Scripts failed...[temp_var]

I want to get rid of ("Scripts failed..." + str(l)) part. Any idea?

Comment: How is `list1` created?

Comment: It is getting created by values which are returned by map function

Comment: eg. p = Pool(processes = 2)  list1 = p.map(function1, list2). Here function1 will return some variables which are getting collected in list1.